# Xcode iOS appicon assets drag and drop - am I doing this wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icons, xcasset

I am curious if I am doing this wrong or is this really this much work to place the icons for different sizes?

I have the app icons for my app with following names:

```
├── iPad
│   ├── Icon-76.png
│   ├── Icon-76@2x.png
│   ├── Icon-83.5@2x.png
│   ├── Icon-Small-40.png
│   ├── Icon-Small-40@2x.png
│   ├── Icon-Small.png
│   └── Icon-Small@2x.png
├── iPhone
│   ├── Icon-60@2x.png
│   ├── Icon-60@3x.png
│   ├── Icon-Small-40@2x.png
│   ├── Icon-Small-40@3x.png
│   ├── Icon-Small@2x.png
│   └── Icon-Small@3x.png
└── iTunes\ Artwork
    ├── iTunesArtwork
    └── iTunesArtwork@2x
```

as you notice all of them have been named correctly and have the @2x or @3x respectively.

Now the way I place the icons in xcode is to manually drag and drop all 13 of the icons one by one. Is this really the right way? Any better way to do all at once?

I have to change the icons often while development and design and this seems a lot of work.

Comment: Why is that you have to change the icons frequently?

Comment: couple reasons - during alpha and beta testing, we place a alpha and beta sign in the icon. second my designer and i are pretty anal about the icons, so we make the icon then see how it looks on the device screen. Then sometimes have to modify a bit and test again until it's perfect.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/105641/change-app-icon-build-time

Comment: thanks! @markedwardmurray  that seems to help me with having to change the icon for beta and alpha releases